# Trying to run Power Shell script from Azure DevOps pipeline to connect to Azure Windows 2016 vm

Tags: azure, azure-devops

error]Unable to create pssession. Error: 'Connecting to remote server "vm.fqdn" failed with the following error message : The server certificate on the destination computer ("vm.fqdn":5985) has the following errors:
Encountered an internal error in the SSL library. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.'
2020-09-16T12:34:24.2013832Z ##[error]The remote session query failed for "vm.fqdn" with the following error message: The server certificate on the destination computer ("vm.fqdn":5985) has the following errors:
Encountered an internal error in the SSL library.
2020-09-16T12:34:24.2917881Z ##[error]PSSession could not be created for Machine:'"vm.fqdn":5985'
2020-09-16T12:34:24.3578033Z ##[section]Finishing: test powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you encountered here should caused by the 5985 port you specified.

You should not use 5985 port as target port. Because our Azure devops is communicating with target Azure machine via HTTPS(5986).

Please change to use 5986 port after you ensure your target machine meet below prerequisites:

**1)**. Install self-signed certificate to your AzureVM.

**2)**. Configure WinRM service to use HTTPS. Here you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/system-management-components/configure-winrm-for-https).

**3)**. Open 5986 port.

Comment: Will agree that this does work, however I need a solution which will work without winrm. is that possible. I have changed my mind about using winrm

Comment: @JudedeDude, if you still using the task that you encountered above error, I'm afraid **winrm** would be the necessary configuration because the logic of that task is using  'PSSession'. And **Winrm** is the default prerequisite of **PSSession**. Is it possible to change to use another task ?